# How can I align chained methods in Ruby files?

Tags: formatting, alignment, filetype-ruby

I often use `=` to indent lines but my configuration doesn't fit my needs.

Is there an option that indent lines like this:

```ruby
'vim rocks'.capitalize
           .concat(' !')
```

Instead of this:

```ruby
'vim rocks'.capitalize
  .concat(' !')
```

([this post](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/12970/ruby-indentation-align-multiline-method-chains-on-the-leading-dot) propose a solution)

Comment: I'm a little bit confused, because you already link to another post which asks the same question with "this post proposes a solution"; so I'm not sure what you're asking as such? Does that solution not work for you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ruby indentation: align multiline method chains on the leading dot?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/12970/ruby-indentation-align-multiline-method-chains-on-the-leading-dot)

Comment: At first I was looking for a `vimrc` option, but it does not exists. The solution above does not work for me, I believe I'm messing with the files location (recently switch to mac, I'm kinda lost). Sorry for the delay, I haven't got much free time this week !

Comment: You can put the code from that answer in your vimrc, if you put that `inoremap` in a `autocmd filetype ruby`.